# C# call method of type class specified in Generic class

Tags: c#

It seems to me that this example `Animal<Cat> animal = new Animal<Cat>()` was misleading. This generic class is supposed to be a wrapper around another class. 
`Wrapper<Type> wrapper = new Wrapper<Type>` and I wanted to invoke a method that is defined in Type class using wrapper reference.

Comment: `GetType() Typeof both return System.Type` Huh?

Comment: If you are relying on type checking in generics than probably you don't need Generic in first place.

Comment: It depends. Are you trying to call an instance or static method? If it's an instance method, do you actually have an instance of `Cat` to work with? Do you have any generic constraints applied to the type parameter? It *seems* like you're trying to create some sort of mix-in, but there's not enough information here for us to know what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Also, just on the face of it, this seems more like a job for inheritance (`class Cat : Animal`) rather than generics.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: Its an instance method. This isn't a case of inheritance. The example was not appropriate for the question

Comment: I don't understand the -3 here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetType()` is only used to reflect on a class.  Animal determins how the Cat class is used; for instance, if Animal is defined as:

```
public class Animal<T>
{
   public T Object { get; set; }
}
```

You would reference it via:

```
Animal<Cat> animal = new Animal<Cat>();
animal.Object.Meow();
```

It's all in how Animal exposes the generic type.

Comment: Thanks. There was no way to expose the generic type in generic class but `public T Object { get; set; }` does the job.

Answer (score 0):

The Cat class must have the same base or implement the same interface. Ideally the constraint would be also specified in where clause in Animal class definition. Then you can call anything that is in base class or interface. That´s how generics work.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are doing Generics, I suppose the method you're looking for isn't only in `Cat`, but in other classes to.

Therefore, I would make an interface with that method

```
public interface Walker {
     void Walk();
}
```

And then have all your classes implement that method:

```
public class Cat implements Walker {
     public void Walk() {
          //Do Something..
     }
}

public class Dog implements Walker {
     public void Walk() {
          //Do Something..
     }
}
```

Then, in you `Animal` definition, you would have something like this:

```
public class Animal<SomeAnimal> where SomeAnimal : Walker, new() {
      //...
}
```

And then from your `Animal` class, you can instantiate a new `SomeAnimal` and call the `Walk` method:

```
public void Walk() {
     SomeAnimal animal = new SomeAnimal();
     animal.Walk();
}
```

alternatively, you can omit the `new` constraint in the class definition, and have your `Walker` instance set by a property:

```
public class Animal<SomeAnimal> where SomeAnimal : Walker {

    public SomeAnimal Animal { set; }

    public void Walk() {
         Animal.Walk();
    }

}
```

Comment: The method is only in the Type class. Have a look at the edited question